# creating paid apps in official android market

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

i want to create a paid app in google play store. can anyone tell me how to do it here is my main activity

```
`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//private Button button;
private WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Get webview
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index.html");
// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.disclaimer) {

        Intent k = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
        k.putExtra(cf.droiddev.oursolarsystem.Webscreen.URL, 
            "file:///android_asset/Disclaimer.html");
        startActivity(k);
        return true;    
    }

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {

        Intent j = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(j);
        return true;
    }

if(item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit App");
                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
                }
                });
                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 }`
```

and here is my main activity.xml

`

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

any help would be appreciated. i tried documentation from google but it gives my project errors

Comment: I have upvoted it to cancel the stupid downvote (which was without a comment).

Comment: You'll need to publish your app ( http://teamtreehouse.com/library/publish-an-android-app?cid=1000 ) then specify in the [dev console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) your listing price.

Comment: @RohitGupta Didn't downvote, but downvotes don't need comments and are not stupid. They are opinions. Upvoting just to cancel someone's opinion is bad practice. The question is bad, since the code has nothing to do with the actual question and the question would be answered by going to Google's docs.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, really,  how does downvoting without a comment help anyone; least of all the OP.  How does he know what he has done wrong ?  And if the question would be answered by going to Google Docs then why not tell him and vote for the question to be closed ?  That would be more fruitful than arguing about my opinion.  :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta I don't argue, of course it's better to comment. But voting is for the value of the question, not a way to say you disagree with someone else's vote.

Answer (score 1):

Paid applications have no differences compared to the free ones. When you submit your app in the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) you'll be able to specify its price - whether it is 0$ or more. You can not submit it as free and make it paid after!

If you'd like to have paid content in the application (like buying more lives in most of the games, for example) is a little different. It requires both implementation changes and configurations from the Google Play Console. [Here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) is the official documentation for such transactions.